# Zammad: error in zammad run rails r "Setting.set('es_url', 'http://localhost:9200')"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, zammad

I am installing zammad in Ubuntu 22.04.1, and when I run this command:

```
zammad run rails r "Setting.set('es_url', 'http://localhost:9200')"
```

got this error

```
/opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/openssl-3.0.0/lib/openssl.so) - /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/openssl-3.0.0/lib/openssl.so (LoadError)
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/openssl-3.0.0/lib/openssl.rb:13:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/application.rb:6:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails.rb:13:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/all.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/config/application.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/runner/runner_command.rb:33:in `perform'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /opt/zammad/bin/rails:10:in `<main>'
```

and I tried this, but it is not helping either

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/bin/openssl" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 is currently not supported in zammad 5.2x! Will be done in next version 5.3 or so.

Regards